# how to show a specific interval of date in the date field?

Tags: php, input

I like to insert a date of birth field in the php form? The range of values to be entered must be in between two years(ex:1988-12-20 to 1992-1-1). I am just a starter in php.`<input type="date" name="dob">`

Comment: is that manually inputted?

Comment: Better to use jQuery datepicker (http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) for restricting the date, instead of doing manually (if you are doing so).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this *between two years(ex:1988-12-20 to 1992-1-1)*

```
<input type="date" name="bday" min="1988-12-20" max="1992-01-01" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with html5 easily

```
<input type="date" name="bday" min="1990-01-02" max="2010-01-02" />
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way is to use the Jquery Datepicker.

```
  <html>
    <head>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(function() {
            $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                minDate: '1988-12-20',
                maxDate: '1992-1-1'
            });
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p> 
    </body>
</html>
```